# Possible side effects of deer antler velvet

Tags: side-effects, allergy, medical-myths, growth-hormones

My doctor suggested I try deer antler velvet. But I am not sure about it.

Does deer antler velvet have any side effects? Does it help growth? Are there any scientific studies about it?

Comment: Welcome to HealthSE! Please take the [tour](https://health.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [help](https://health.stackexchange.com/help). Please refine your question via an [edit](https://health.stackexchange.com/posts/14936/edit) with the help of [how to ask](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Never heard of that before. If you explain a bit on what this is and what your research has revealed so far your question will improve a lot.